# Testing a ruby block with minitest

Tags: ruby, tdd, block, minitest

What would be the best way of testing a Ruby block with minitest. Rspec seems to have a set of yield matchers. Is there something similar in minitest

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: I asked a [similar thing here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090884/how-can-i-mock-with-a-block-in-minitest)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSpec's yield matchers are simple syntactic sugar over a fairly simple way of testing blocks.

1. Initialize a local variable before the block
2. Call the method, and pass a block that mutates the local variable you declared in #1.
3. Verify the value of the variable afterwards.

So, you can do something like this:

```
block_called = false
do_something { block_called = true }
assert_true block_called
```

Alternately, if you like the syntax and failure output of rspec-expectations, you can easily use it with minitest (or any other testing framework); I [blogged about this](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/07/mixing-and-matching-parts-of-rspec#using_minitest_and_rspecexpectations) if you want the nitty-gritty details.