# How can I mock with a block in minitest?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, minitest

Hopefully a simple question for MiniTest folks..

I have a section of code which I'll condense into an example here:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(name)
    @sqs    = Aws::SQS::Client.new
    @id     = @sqs.create_queue( queue_name: name ).fetch(:queue_url)
    @poller = Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.new(@id)
  end
  def pick_first
    @poller.poll(idle_timeout: 60) do |message|
      process_msg(message) if some_condition(message)
    end
  end
```

How can I mock/stub/something-else so that I can feed a `message` through to be tested by the `some_condition()` and possibly processed with `process_msg()`?

I.e. I want to test the `@poller.poll(idle_timeout: 60) do |message|`.

I have tried to stub the `Aws::SQS::QueuePoller#new` with a mock poller, but it's not yielding the message to `|message|` just returning it..

This is what I have, which is **not** working:

```
mockqueue = MiniTest::Mock.new

mocksqs = MiniTest::Mock.new
mocksqs.expect :create_queue, mockqueue, [Hash]

mockpoller = MiniTest::Mock.new                                                                                                                         
mockpoller.expect :poll, 'message', [{ idle_timeout: 60 }]

Aws::SQS::Client.stub :new, mocksqs do
  Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.stub :new, mockpoller do
    queue = Foo.new(opts)
    queue.pick_first
  end
end
```

If I receive a variable in `#pick_first`, that's where the mock puts it, not into `|message|`:

```
def pick_first
    receiver = @poller.poll(idle_timeout: 60) do |message|
      process_msg(message) if some_condition(message)
    end
    puts receiver # this shows my 'message' !!! WHYYYY??
  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case someone else has the same question.

I asked for help on this via Twitter, and the author of MiniTest, Ryan Davis (aka @zenspider on github / @the_zenspider on Twitter) gave a quick answer along with an invite to submit the question to the MiniTest github issue tracker.

[I did so](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/545), and got a couple of great responses, from Ryan and also from Pete Higgins (@phiggins on github), which I reproduce here in their entirety. Thank you to both of you for your help!

---

[@phiggins](https://github.com/phiggins) said:

> What about something like:
>
> ```
> class Foo   def initialize(name, opts={})
>   @sqs    = Aws::SQS::Client.new
>   @id     = @sqs.create_queue( queue_name: name ).fetch(:queue_url)
>   @poller = opts.fetch(:poller) { Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.new(@id) }   end
>
>   def pick_first
>     @poller.poll(idle_timeout: 60) do |message|
>     process_msg(message) if some_condition(message)
>     end
>   end
> end
>
> # later, in your tests
> describe Foo do
>   it "does the thing in the block" do
>   # could be moved into top-level TestPoller, or into shared setup, etc.
>   poller = Object.new
>   def poller.poll(*) ; yield ; end
>
>   foo = Foo.new("lol", :poller => poller)
>   foo.pick_first
>
>   assert foo.some_state_was_updated
>   end
> end
> ```

---

[@zenspider](https://github.com/zenspider) said:

> NOTE: I'm anti-mock. I'm almost anti-stub for that matter. IMHO, if
>   you can't test something without mocking it, you probably have a
>   design issue. Calibrate accordingly against the text below.
>
> I suggested using Liskov Substitution Principal (LSP) because I was
>   focused on testing that process_msg did the right thing in that
>   context. The idea is simple, subclass, override the method in
>   question, and use the subclass within the tests. LSP says that testing
>   a subclass is equivalent to testing the superclass.
>
> In the case of the polling object, you have three concerns (polling,
>   filtering, and processing) going on in that method, one of whom you
>   shouldn't be testing (because it is third-party code). I'd refactor to
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> class Foo
>   # ....
>
>   def poll
>     @poller.poll(idle_timeout: 60) do |message|
>       yield message
>     end
>   end
>
>   def pick_first
>     poll do |message|
>       process_msg(message) if some_condition(message)
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Then testing is a simple matter:
>
> ```
> class TestFoo1 < Foo
>   def poll
>     yield 42 # or whatever
>   end
>
>   # ...
> end
>
> # ...
>
> assert_equal 42, TestFoo1.new.pick_first # some_condition truthy
> assert_nil       TestFoo2.new.pick_first # some_condition falsey
> ```
>
> There are shorter/"rubyier" ways to do this, but they're equivalent to the above and the above illustrates the point better.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to stub something that yields a block and had trouble finding the answer. (Unsure if this is exactly what you were asking.) Here's how to do it.

Here's our class that we want to mock:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    yield(42)
  end
end
```

In our test we instantiate our object:

```
foo = Foo.new
```

Then we can override this method with plain Ruby to do something else:

```
def foo.bar
  yield(16)
end
```

Now when we call it, it calls the stubbed version instead:

```
foo.bar do |value|
  puts value
  # => 16
end
```

Easy enough. This took me awhile to figure out. Hopefully this helps someone :)